# Eloquent: Retrieve recent added records

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, orm, eloquent

Eloquent ORM in Laravel 4.2 drives me crazy. I want to retrieve the recent added records a user has.

I have 3 models: User, Folder, File. A User has many folders and a folder has many files. Also a User has many files through folders (I think I don't need to post my models source here, I hope my description is accurate enough).

```
$files = Auth::User() -> files;
return $files;
```

This code shows me all files a user has.

```
$files = Auth::User() -> files() -> orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC') -> take(5) -> get();
return $files;
```

This code is actually doing what I want. Giving back the last 5 records which have been edited. But I want to mak this reusable and extend my model with a function. And this is where I fail:

```
# File.php (model):

public function recentFiles()
{
    return $this -> orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC') -> take(5) -> get();
}


# Controller:

$files = Auth::User() -> files -> recentFiles;
return $files;
```

This ends in a "undefined property: $recentFiles" error. 
What is my problem?

Thanks

Comment: Are you sure this is what is creating the error? I don't see `$recentUnits` anywhere.

Comment: @Jerodev Yes,sorry. I have the same problem with another model and relations. I just pasted the wrong error here. replace Units with files and it would fit my post ^^

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can achieve that using the [Query Scopes](http://laravel.com/docs/4.2/eloquent#query-scopes).

```
# File.php (model)

    public function scopeRecentFiles($query)
    {
        return $query->orderBy('updated_at', 'DESC')->take(5);
    }

# Controller

$files = Auth::User()->files()->recentFiles()->get();
return $files;
```

Comment: Ah that was the word I missed: "scopes". That's why I didn't noticed it in the doc. Thanks!